# redirect from another div

Tags: cakephp

From my home page am showing a popupdiv.on submiting the popup form i need my home page to redirect.but my popup form is redirecting . How to make my home page redirect, after completing controller function.

Now am using $this->redirect(home/action)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get a reference to the homepage through java script from the pop-up win:

```
window.opener.location.href = "new page";
```